# Unsupported protocol while download tar.gz package

Tags: linux, build, download, cmake

I have just upgrade my CMake from version 2.8 to 3.2.

It's working like a charm in CMake 2.8 but, after the upgrade, it's failing.

I'm trying to build third party library using `ExternalProject_Add()` CMake function.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  luacov
  URL https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
  DOWNLOAD_DIR ${EXTERNAL_PROJECT_DOWNLOAD_DIR}
  CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${MY_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
  SOURCE_DIR ${EXTERNAL_PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/luacov
  BINARY_DIR ${EXTERNAL_PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/luacov
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ""
)
```

**MY OBSERVATION:**

1. Using `GIT_REPOSITORY` option, `ExternalProject_Add()` allow `http` and `https` protocol to download external project.
2. Using `URL` option, `ExternalProject_Add()` only allow `http`, but not `https` protocol to download external project.

**PROBLEM:**

Is there any way to download and build external project using `https` protocol?

**ERROR:**

```
[ 16%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'luacov'
-- downloading...
 src='https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz'
 dst='/home/build/my_build/external_projects/downloads/v0.7.tar.gz'
 timeout='none'
CMake Error at /home/build/my_build/luacov-prefix/src/luacov-stamp/download-luacov.cmake:21 (message):
 error: downloading
'https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz' failed

status_code: 1
status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
log: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Closing connection -1

make[3]: *** [luacov-prefix/src/luacov-stamp/luacov-download] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/luacov.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/luacov.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [luacov] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my `ExternalProject_Add()`, I have use `GIT_REPOSITORY` insted of `URL` option.

```
#URL https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov.git
```

And `luacov` download and build successfully.

For any `https` protocol use `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND` option of `ExternalProject_Add()` function.

```
DOWNLOAD_COMMAND wget https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
```

and its working as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you extract the archive when using `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`? When downloaded via URL this is done automatically but this seems not to be the case when you do it this way.

Answer (score 25):

The problem may be that the CURL library shipped with CMake isn't build with SSL support by default. I had to compile cmake with:

```
./bootstrap --system-curl
make
sudo make install
```

... and that worked, because my system's curl has SSL support.

Answer (score 14):

What it worked for me is the following:

1. Update openssl

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
   ```
2. Modify bootstrap file to enable CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL. Replace this [line](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/4e96dc02c3a305644d935550ae3dd01df61a45b0/bootstrap#L1518) by:

   ```
   cmake_options="-DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP=1 -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=ON"
   ```
3. Run bootstrap script normally in cmake folder

   ```
   /@path_to_cmake/bootstrap
   ```

Comment: the line number is out of date. which line is it now?

Comment: if the line nubmer doesnt match, then search for cmake_options in the file

Comment: Just installing `libssl-dev` was enough for me. (Ubuntu 16.04)
When OpenSSL and `libssl-div` are installed, CMake will be build with SSL support.
There is no need to edit the bootstrap file or manually giving it the parameters on the command-line.

Comment: Rather than modifying the bootstrap source code, use the `bootstrap --init` option. Example: `echo "SET(CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL CACHE BOOL ON FORCE)" > CMAKE_USE_SSL_ON.cmake && ./bootstrap --init=CMAKE_USE_SSL_ON.cmake`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem building a library in a computer in which CMake had not support to https protocol.

I had to build cmake myself with the option -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=ON as suggested by @dekkard's comment.

Answer (score 2):

For CMake 3.8.0 this worked for me:

1. Install/update openssl:

   ```
   yum install openssl openssl-devel
   ```
2. Adapt the solution from a [CMake forum reply](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-June/063628.html) by Brad King:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/software/cmake-3.8.0/ --parallel=${NPROC} -- \ 
       -/DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL:BOOL=ON
   make -j ${NPROC} 
   make install
   ```
3. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for reply. +1 for other option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like with Cmake 3.2.1 it works as expected.

Here's my sample project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(TestDownload)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/bin/g++")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/path/to/bin/gcc")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
  luacov
  URL https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
  DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/luacov
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

And the commands:

```
$ cd project
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
...
$ make all
Scanning dependencies of target luacov
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'luacov'
[ 25%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'luacov'
-- downloading...
     src='https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov/archive/v0.7.tar.gz'
     dst='/tmp/project/build/luacov/v0.7.tar.gz'
     timeout='none'
-- [download 7% complete]
-- [download 21% complete]
-- [download 76% complete]
-- [download 100% complete]
-- downloading... done
-- verifying file...
     file='/tmp/project/build/luacov/v0.7.tar.gz'
-- verifying file... warning: did not verify file - no URL_HASH specified?
-- extracting...
     src='/tmp/project/build/luacov/v0.7.tar.gz'
     dst='/tmp/project/build/luacov-prefix/src/luacov'
-- extracting... [tar xfz]
-- extracting... [analysis]
-- extracting... [rename]
-- extracting... [clean up]
-- extracting... done
[ 37%] No patch step for 'luacov'
[ 50%] No update step for 'luacov'
...
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your reply. I'm following the same steps that you have mention in reply. But still facing the error that I have updated in my quetion below `EDIT` tag.

Comment: Hm, that's a different deal. Don't know if it's still true, but here's what they say ( http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-December/041295.html ): ```CMake builds its own curl, without ssl support by default, unless you
point it to the system curl.

You can rebuild CMake with the CMAKE_USE_OPENSSL ON if you have all
the right supporting system libraries installed.```

Answer (score -3):

I will often just modify the url from https to http.

Comment: That's not a solution that's dirty workaround which will not work in many cases, as many pages are only accessible via HTTPS.