# cmake is unable to download by protocol HTTPS while own cmake option procedure

Tags: curl, https, cmake, openssl, libcurl

When I aply my cmake option

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/luke/cv/last/opencv_contrib/modules  ..
```

it will cause faults (written in warnings) with downloading some necessary files by HTTPS protocol.

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:190 (message):
  IPPICV: Download failed: 1;"Unsupported protocol"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  /home/luke/cv/last/oc/opencv/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/CAWU6fdY) is full output- result of entered CMake command. An info from file :

```
  CMakeDownloadLog.txt
```

is also shown [here](https://pastebin.com/Rf6CAKQd). Seems like libcurl is not working. Ok I installed the last release of curl and also OpenSSL and I have make `./configure --with-ssl` comand. When I see configured [log of libcurl](https://pastebin.com/UBvRs8d0) there I can see HTTPS on enum of protocols. Soo **that should be supported**. But Cmake again while configuration and generating makes still that same fails with downloads written in that warnings ( shown above in my links ).  **CMake tells: not supported** or **disabled in libcurl** but **libcurl says** (it seems like..) **suported**. Ah. I am thinking about it but dont know what else is wrong.

Does anybody know what could be wrong or do you have any idea/tips please ??

Comment: Well. It seems like maybe CMake is not using libcurl but is set to use some own lib? I was searching about it but dont know how to set it. Or How make sure that cmake is really set to use libcurl which I have updated in my UNIX system.

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816529/unsupported-protocol-while-download-tar-gz-package
You can have a try.

Answer (score 3):

Since you were still seeing the error after installing the latest curl and openssl packages - and even building libcurl yourself - I suspect you may have built cmake yourself using its bootstrapper.

If that's the case, it's worth noting that cmake's `bootstrap` script will ignore system packages and use internal versions of all of cmake's dependencies, by default. Unfortunately, that includes a version of libcurl without ssl support. That's why it wasn't seeing the versions you added to your system and you still got the https unsupported or disabled protocol errors.

Fortunately, the `bootstrap` script is configurable, and you can tell it to use various system libraries instead of its internal ones! This is how you can see the available bootstrap options:

`cmake-repo> ./bootstrap --help`

Which will output something like this:

```
Usage: ../bootstrap [<options>...] [-- <cmake-options>...]
Options: [defaults in brackets after descriptions]
Configuration:
  --help                  print this message
  --version               only print version information
  --verbose               display more information
  --parallel=n            bootstrap cmake in parallel, where n is
                          number of nodes [1]
  --enable-ccache         Enable ccache when building cmake
  --init=FILE             load FILE as script to populate cache
  --system-libs           use all system-installed third-party libraries
                          (for use only by package maintainers)
  --no-system-libs        use all cmake-provided third-party libraries
                          (default)
  --system-curl           use system-installed curl library
  --no-system-curl        use cmake-provided curl library (default)
  --system-expat          use system-installed expat library
  --no-system-expat       use cmake-provided expat library (default)
  --system-jsoncpp        use system-installed jsoncpp library
  --no-system-jsoncpp     use cmake-provided jsoncpp library (default)
  --system-zlib           use system-installed zlib library
  --no-system-zlib        use cmake-provided zlib library (default)
  --system-bzip2          use system-installed bzip2 library
  --no-system-bzip2       use cmake-provided bzip2 library (default)
  --system-liblzma        use system-installed liblzma library
  --no-system-liblzma     use cmake-provided liblzma library (default)
  --system-libarchive     use system-installed libarchive library
  --no-system-libarchive  use cmake-provided libarchive library (default)
  --system-librhash       use system-installed librhash library
  --no-system-librhash    use cmake-provided librhash library (default)
  --system-libuv          use system-installed libuv library
  --no-system-libuv       use cmake-provided libuv library (default)

  --qt-gui                build the Qt-based GUI (requires Qt >= 4.2)
  --no-qt-gui             do not build the Qt-based GUI (default)
  --qt-qmake=<qmake>      use <qmake> as the qmake executable to find Qt

  --sphinx-info           build Info manual with Sphinx
  --sphinx-man            build man pages with Sphinx
  --sphinx-html           build html help with Sphinx
  --sphinx-qthelp         build qch help with Sphinx
  --sphinx-build=<sb>     use <sb> as the sphinx-build executable
  --sphinx-flags=<flags>  pass <flags> to sphinx-build executable

Directory and file names:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install files in tree rooted at PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --bindir=DIR            install binaries in PREFIX/DIR
                          [bin]
  --datadir=DIR           install data files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [share/cmake-3.14]
  --docdir=DIR            install documentation files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [doc/cmake-3.14]
  --mandir=DIR            install man pages files in PREFIX/DIR/manN
                          [man]
  --xdgdatadir=DIR        install XDG specific files in PREFIX/DIR
                          [share]
```

The important one for solving this particular issue is the `--system-curl` option.

Here's how I use it when building from source. (Unlike the cmake docs usage example, I prefer to build in a subfolder instead of the source directory itself.):

```
cmake-repo> mkdir build && cd build
cmake-repo/build> ../bootstrap --system-curl
cmake-repo/build> make -j<core-count> # use max cores for a fast build
cmake-repo/build> sudo make install
```

Once the newly-build cmake replaces the non-ssl version, you should be able to avoid those pesky download errors when building opencv from source (which is what it looks like you were doing.)