# CMAKE_USE_SYSTEM_CURL is ON but a curl is not found

Tags: curl, cmake

I was trying to install cmake with the system-curl, with `./bootstrap --system-curl`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816529/unsupported-protocol-while-download-tar-gz-package). Doing that, I got:

```
    -- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:413 (message):
  CMAKE_USE_SYSTEM_CURL is ON but a curl is not found!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:682 (CMAKE_BUILD_UTILITIES)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/temp/cmake-3.14.5/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/temp/cmake-3.14.5/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running initial CMake
```

Answer (score 7):

For me running `./bootstrap --no-system-curl` led to errors when running cmake on open-cv, because the https protocol could not be found. So I needed to get `./bootstrap --system-curl` running.

The solution is to install curl dev dependencies. These are needed by cmake, not just curl.

I ran:

```sh
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also just use cmake-provided curl library by running  `./bootstrap --no-system-curl` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, I solved looking at 
[this issue on Github](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/328#issuecomment-198672048). In particular, I downloaded the curl source code from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
 and compiled curl with:

```
/CurlExtractFolder$ ./configure --with--ssl
/CurlExtractFolder$ make
/CurlExtractFolder$ sudo make install
```